# How to Fix PHP segmentation fault?

Tags: php, segmentation-fault, gdb

I am trying to run script which parses .torrent files using nohup php file.php & after few seconds it says segmentation fault core dumped. I have tried:

**gdb /usr/bin/php core.19242**

```
[root@prod1 home]# gdb /usr/bin/php core.19242
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-64.el7
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/php...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/php.debug...done.
done.
[New LWP 19242]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `php parse_files.php'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  __find_specmb (format=0x7f5a29cc2c3e "%s\n") at printf-parse.h:109
109       return (const unsigned char *) __strchrnul ((const char *) format, '%');
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install libcurl-7.43.0-1.0.cf.rhel7.x86_64 libssh2-1.6.0-2.0.cf.rhel7.x86_64
```

**I have tried installing lots of packages which gdb suggested me to install using**

```
debuginfo-install --enablerepo=webtatic-debuginfo bzip2-libs-1.0.6-12.el7.x86_64 cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.26-17.el7.x86_64 freetype-2.4.11-10.el7_1.1.x86_64 gmp-6.0.0-11.el7.x86_64 keyutils-libs-1.5.8-3.el7.x86_64 libX11-1.6.0-2.1.el7.x86_64 libXau-1.0.8-2.1.el7.x86_64 libXpm-3.5.10-5.1.el7.x86_64 libcurl-7.43.0-1.0.cf.rhel7.x86_64 libidn-1.28-3.el7.x86_64 libjpeg-turbo-1.2.90-5.el7.x86_64 libpng-1.5.13-5.el7.x86_64 libselinux-2.2.2-6.el7.x86_64 libssh2-1.6.0-2.0.cf.rhel7.x86_64 libxcb-1.9-5.el7.x86_64 nspr-4.10.8-1.el7_1.x86_64 nss-3.19.1-3.el7_1.x86_64 nss-softokn-freebl-3.16.2.3-9.el7.x86_64 nss-util-3.19.1-1.el7_1.x86_64 openldap-2.4.39-6.el7.x86_64 pcre-8.32-14.el7.x86_64 sqlite-3.7.17-4.el7.x86_64 t1lib-5.1.2-14.el7.x86_64 xz-libs-5.1.2-9alpha.el7.x86_64
```

But now when i am doing:

**debuginfo-install libcurl-7.43.0-1.0.cf.rhel7.x86_64 libssh2-1.6.0-2.0.cf.rhel7.x86_64**

```
[root@prod1 home]# debuginfo-install libcurl-7.43.0-1.0.cf.rhel7.x86_64 libssh2-1.6.0-2.0.cf.rhel7.x86_64
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, fastestmirror
enabling epel-debuginfo
enabling base-debuginfo
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.netelligent.ca
 * epel: mirror.cogentco.com
 * epel-debuginfo: mirror.cogentco.com
 * extras: centos.mirror.ca.planethoster.net
 * updates: centos.mirrors.atwab.net
Could not find debuginfo for main pkg: libcurl-7.43.0-1.0.cf.rhel7.x86_64
Package glibc-debuginfo-2.17-78.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package e2fsprogs-debuginfo-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package krb5-debuginfo-1.12.2-14.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libidn-debuginfo-1.28-3.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package openldap-debuginfo-2.4.39-6.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package nspr-debuginfo-4.10.8-1.el7_1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package nss-debuginfo-3.19.1-3.el7_1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package nss-util-debuginfo-3.19.1-1.el7_1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package libssh2-1.6.0-2.0.cf.rhel7.x86_64
Package zlib-debuginfo-1.2.7-13.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:openssl-debuginfo-1.0.1e-42.el7.9.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No debuginfo packages available to install
```

i even tried with

```
debuginfo-install --enablerepo=webtatic libcurl-7.43.0-1.0.cf.rhel7.x86_64 libssh2-1.6.0-2.0.cf.rhel7.x86_64
```

How can I know what is causing this segmentation fault? While I execute PHP script using nohup, I have got nohup.out file with lots of lines like this
**tail nohup.out**

```
[root@prod1 home]# tail nohup.out
Notice: String offset cast occurred in /home/data/nginx/html/admin/Bcode.php on line 145
PHP Notice:  String offset cast occurred in /home/data/nginx/html/admin/Bcode.php on line 118

Notice: String offset cast occurred in /home/data/nginx/html/admin/Bcode.php on line 118
PHP Notice:  String offset cast occurred in /home/data/nginx/html/admin/Bcode.php on line 168

Notice: String offset cast occurred in /home/data/nginx/html/admin/Bcode.php on line 168
PHP Notice:  String offset cast occurred in /home/data/nginx/html/admin/Bcode.php on line 170

Notice: String offset cast occurred in /home/data/nginx/html/admin/Bcode.php on line 170
```

Are the notices causing php to segfault?

I am using older library TorrentParse GTK for parsing torrent files.

Comment: It is not the notices themselves causing php to segfault. It is some function, probably inside a library php uses. The functions are typically coded in c language. If you could install that single debug info package that cannot be found you would be able to locate exactly which library and at what code position the error occurs. Most likely it is some string handling function call. With that information you could look for a fixed version or even fix it yourself to recompile the library. But it won't be easy to locate that package, redhat linux is not that common these days...

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for your input, ill try to install those packages again, is it because of the older version of php torrent parsing library , i ll try with newer version too., i am using centos 7 x64.

Comment: you could also try to locate the source package of the library and compile it yourself. That will also create the debug info package along the way. You'd have everything out of one go.

Comment: just checked i am using latest version of php library to parse files, i guess, its the one file which is causing this. what can i do if i find out what/which file is causing this ? i have to parse the files ..

Comment: If that really is a "library" written in php, then this will certainly _not_ cause the segmentation fault. PHP scripts do not directly address memory. The code causing the violation must be either within php or withing one of the php modules activated at startup time. Those are typically binary data compiled from c based sources. Such modules are a single file when compiled, nothing you can parse or adjust manually. You have to dive into the c source.

Comment: Even if you are using the latest version of some library that does not mean that locally recompiling and linking the package does not solve the issue. Segmentation faults are often caused by code linked to something. The result you create locally is typically different to packages you load from somewhere else, since the local package is based on exactly those packages and versions you have installed locally whilst compiling and linking the source.

Comment: It might be that you somehow get around the fault by replacing part of the php code, so that the circumstances that lead to the segmentation fault do not occur any more. But I do not see an easy way to identify what changes might cause that effect, sorry.